# Register multiple EventHandlers for one portlet

Tags: event-handling, liferay, portlet

I would like to register more than one `EventHandler` in a Portlet in my `portlet.xml`.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

When trying to add a second block of `init-param` i get an error:

[image]

Than i tryed to add multiple `EventHandler` in one `init-param` block, but i get this error:

[image]

Can i register more than one `EventHandler` classes?

if yes, how is it done correctly?

Comment: Could you replace the screenshots with code examples as text (see context help how to do that)? That way your issue is better readable and findable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bridge is expecting only one event handler, but you can create one that delegates to both instances:

```
public class BridgeEventHandler {
    private BridgeEventHandler eventHandler1 = new ...;
    private BridgeEventHandler eventHandler2 = new ...;

    public EventNavigationResult handleEvent(FacesContext facesContext, Event event);
        EventNavigationResult result = eventHandler1.handleEvent(facesContext, event);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        return eventHandler2.handleEvent(facesContext, event);
    }
}
```